# Accessing an EJB deployed on websphere community server using Open EJB?

Tags: ejb-3.0, websphere, ejb, openejb

How can I access an EJB deployed on websphere community server using Open EJB? I'm trying to use code like the following but am not sure what to use for a URL. Note I've tried port 2809 and 1099 with ejb: and IIOP URL prefixes.

```
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory");
            props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"IIOP://127.0.0.1:2809");
            Context ctx = new InitialContext(props);
            Object ref = ctx.lookup("CalculatorRemote  ");
```

CalculatorImpl   h = (CalculatorImpl )PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ref,CalculatorImpl.class);

Comment: What is the client? A webapp also deployed to WAS or a stand-alone app? Or ...?

Comment: I want the client to be a stand-alone console app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"ejbd://127.0.0.1:4201");
```